# remove moving objects using warped perspective image

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, computer-vision, homography

**Intro:** From what I understand, given 2 images of the same scene with moving objects, I can make a mean on each pixel in order to "remove" the moving objects (it will have ghosting effects, but if I'll repeat with several images it will do fine).

However, this wouldn't work at all if I have different scenes, so I want to move all my images to the same scene (warping the perspective) and then do the suggested above.

---

I want to remove moving-objects from movie-frames I have. To do so, I find the matching key-points between 2 images,  use RANSAC to remove outliers, and warp the perspective of image A to image B's perspective to get a warped image.

Now I want to that warped image to be in the same size of the `src,dst` images but that's not what I get:[image]

Eventually I want to have a full warped image from several frames, and to use it to remove objects that move from frame to frame.

1. How to create the warped images in full size?
2. How to find the corresponding pixels on which I want to mean the values in order to delete moving objects?

---

```
# find key points + features of a given image
def get_keyPoints_and_features(img):
    descriptor = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    kps, features = descriptor.detectAndCompute(img, None)
    kps = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in kps])
    return kps, features

# match key points of 2 images 
def match_key_points(a, b, ratio = 0.75):
    # unpack 
    kpsA, featuresA = a
    kpsB, featuresB = b

    matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create("BruteForce")
    rawMatches = matcher.knnMatch(featuresA, featuresB, 2)
    matches = []

    # remove outliers using RANSAC
    for m in rawMatches:
        if len(m) == 2 and m[0].distance < m[1].distance * ratio:
            matches.append((m[0].trainIdx, m[0].queryIdx))

    # must have more than 4 matches
    # the more matches we have, the more noise robust it will be
    assert(len(matches) > 4)
    ptsA = np.float32([kpsA[i] for (_, i) in matches])
    ptsB = np.float32([kpsB[i] for (i, _) in matches])
    (H, status) = cv2.findHomography(ptsA, ptsB, method = cv2.RANSAC, 
                                        ransacReprojThreshold = 0.4)
    return matches, H

# warp src image to have perspective like dst image using the 
# homogrpahy between both images
def warp_perspective(src, dst):
    # read images
    a,b = cv2.imread(src), cv2.imread(dst)

    # generate key points and features
    kps_and_features_a = get_keyPoints_and_features(a)
    kps_and_features_b = get_keyPoints_and_features(b)

    # get homography
    _, H = match_key_points(kps_and_features_a, kps_and_features_b)

    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(a, H, (a.shape[1], a.shape[0]))
    inv_warped = cv2.warpPerspective(warped, inv(H), (a.shape[1], a.shape[0]))

    cv2.imshow("a", a)
    cv2.imshow("b", b)
    cv2.imshow("warped", warped)
    cv2.imshow("inv_warped", inv_warped)
    cv2.moveWindow("a",0,0)
    cv2.moveWindow("b",0,370)
    cv2.moveWindow("warped",600,0)
    cv2.moveWindow("inv_warped",600,370)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    # get images
    path = r'...'
    images = [os.path.join(path, file) for file in os.listdir(path)]
    warp_perspective(images[0], images[1])

main()
```